# Limit total concurrent tasks running

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, concurrency, azure-web-app-service

I have a method `Create` which is executed whenever a new message is seen on the service bus message queue (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/).
I am trying to limit the total number of concurrent tasks that can run in parallel for all calls of `Create` to 5 tasks.
In my code Parallel.ForEach does not seem to do anything.

I have tried to add a mutex/lock around the `makePdfAsync()` invocation like this:

```
mutex.WaitOne();
if(curretNumTasks < MaxTasks)
{
    tasks.Add(makePdfAsync(form));
}
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

but it is extremely slow and makes the service bus throw.

How do I limit the number of concurrent tasks all invocations of `Create` creates?

```
public async Task Create(List<FormModel> forms)
 {
     var tasks = new List<Task>();

     Parallel.ForEach(forms, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, form =>
     {
         tasks.Add(makePdfAsync(form));
     });
     await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(tasks), Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)));
 }

 public async Task makePdfAsync()
 {
     var message = new PdfMessageModel();
     message.forms = new List<FormModel>() { form };

     var retry = 10;
     var uri = new Uri("http://localhost.:8007");
     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

     using (var wc = new WebClient())
     {
         wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

         // reconnect with delay in case process is not ready
         while (true)
         {
             try
             {
                 await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri, json);
                 break;
             }
             catch
             {
                 if (retry-- == 0) throw;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

TL;DR. `Create` is a method  on a class, it is called on many instances simultaneously. The concurrency is two fold; Several invocations of `Create` simultaneously and within each invocation of `Create` several tasks run concurrently.
How do I limit the total number of tasks running at any one point?

Comment: You are just building the tasks list parallel, you're not executing it via the parallel.foreach.. all tasks are executed in `Task.WhenAll(tasks)`  The `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5` doesn't have any effect on the `Task.WhenAll(tasks)`..  So the `Parallel.ForEach` has no use in this code.

Comment: This is the second time you've asked this question, and the answer is still the same: use `SemaphoreSlim`. If this isn't applicable to your scenario for some reason, then please update your question to clarify why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using a system wide semaphore?

for example :

```
var throttle = new Semaphore(5,5,"pdftaskthrottle");

if (throttle.WaitOne(5000)){
    try{
       //do some task / thread stuff
       .....
    } catch(Exception ex){
       // handle
    } finally {
      //always remember to release the semaphore
      throttle.Release();
    }
} else {
   //we timed out ... try again?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you effectively want a producer/consumer queue with a limit of 5 tasks. [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) would be the best if that's what you're after. It has very good performance as internally it uses `SemaphoreSlim` to do the blocking when necessary. Also you can leverage `Task` together e.g. creating a `BlockingCollection<Task<T>>`. "C# in a nutshell" has a good section of this; see code below as a general example. Also try avoid using kernel-mode synchronisation construct like mutex if possible as they're slow (you have to pay for transiting from managed code into native code!).

```
        class PCQueue : IDisposable
        {
            private BlockingCollection<Task> _taskQueue = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
            public PCQueue(int workerCount)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(Consume);
            }

            public Task Enqueue(Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken = default(CancellationToken))
            {
                //! A task object can either be generated using TaskCompletionSource or instantiated directly (an unstarted or cold task!).
                var task = new Task(action, cancelToken);
                _taskQueue.Add(task); //? Create a cold task and enqueue it.
                return task;
            }

            public Task<TResult> Enqueue<TResult>(Func<TResult> func, CancellationToken cancelToken = default(CancellationToken))
            {
                var task = new Task<TResult>(func, cancelToken);
                _taskQueue.Add(task);
                return task;
            }

            void Consume()
            {
                foreach (var task in _taskQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //! We run the task synchronously on the consumer's thread.
                        if (!task.IsCanceled) task.RunSynchronously();
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException)
                    {
                        //! Handle the unlikely event that the task is canceled in between checking whether it's canceled and running it. 
                        // race condition!
                    }
                }
            }

            public void Dispose() => _taskQueue.CompleteAdding();
        }
```

Comment: You didn't specify an upper bound